# UI-Router $stateParams empty on initial "invalid" route page load

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following code redirect/transition logic in my appConfig for re-pointing of invalid routes:

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/:lang/profile/:keywords/:id', ['$state', '$stateParams', function ($state, $stateParams) {
            $state.transitionTo('root.public-profile.summary', $stateParams, {
            reload: true,
            inherit: false,
            notify: true
        });
```

with Summary route defined as:

```
state('root.public-profile.summary', {
                    url: "/summary",
                    templateUrl: "/templates/public.profile.summary.tpl.html"
            })
```

So when a user attempts to access '/:lang/profile/:keywords/:id' it should redirect/re-point them to /:lang/profile/:keywords/:id/summary. This works fine when a view had been loaded before, if a user attempts to remove the 'summary' portion from the Url, it does gets re-appended automatically as expected. However, if a user copies and pastes 'wrong' link directly in a new browser window, the $stateParams object is empty and thus transition can't happen.

Is that behavior by design and is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You are right Val,

This behaviour is by design.You should see everything in the form of state-diagrams and Whether the transition will happen or not depends on what state is getting activated.What I can see from your snippet is that here you are working with ui-router where states carries more significance then the actual urls.
Not sure what you are trying to achieve but these docs can be helpful to you.
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

Please Comment back for any other concerns or vote up if you are convinced with this answer.

Comment: Gautam thanks for the response. What I am trying to accomplish is essentially, if a user happens to share an invalid/partial url to automatically redirect them to the correct one. Not sure sure how to accomplish that.

Comment: Check out the description of -----otherwise()  method in routeprovider in this doc.https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider.This will help you filter out all the invalid urls and use the needed ones.Thanks